# Null value returned to Apps Script webapp for a certain spreadsheet by server function

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, null

I am trying to return the data in the spreadsheet to an Apps Script published as a webApp. However, for one of my spreadsheets ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1czjIu8G7fPnMNqFDCBkiCq7oq7zRCm3KdvEUjwPdqgQ/edit?usp=sharing)), the returned data is `null`. I logged the the data before returning to make sure that it isn't null, and I can see them in the logs.

This is my code:

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function spreadsheetTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, maxRows, 10);
  Logger.log(data)
  return data;
}
```

```html
<html>
<button type="button" onclick="clcked();">Click Me!</button>
<div id="Message"></div>

<script>
  function clcked(){
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .spreadsheetTest();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: You should be more specific about the log results - you log both in the server function and in the client function. Which is `null`? Both? Just the client? What is being logged? (You should include these example logs in the question).

Comment: Note: this behavior (value -> `null` for some types, such as `Date`) is explicitly identified in documentation for the client-server communication: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)

Comment: Thanks tehhowch. I will take your suggestions for my future posts and thank you for editing my post to make it more readable.

Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have ever experienced the same issue before. When the values with the date format are included in `data` which is retrieved by `getSheetValues()`, the returned values become null. I thought that the issue might occur when the date values are parsed and/or converted, when the values are sent from GAS to Javascript. By this, null is returned. In order to avoid this, I think that there are 2 patterns for your situation. Please chose one of them for your situation.

#### Pattern 1

For the function `spreadsheetTest()`, modify as follows.

From :

```
return data;
```

To :

```
return JSON.stringify(data);
```

#### Pattern 2

For the function `spreadsheetTest()`, modify as follows.

From :

```
var data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, maxRows, 10);
```

To :

```
var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, 10).getDisplayValues();
```

If these are not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi Tanaike,

Thank you so much. You are a legend. It did worked. I had been trying to figure this out for weeks.  :)

Comment: @Himal Samarasekara I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thank you so much. If this was useful for your situation, I'm glad.

Comment: This answer is still relevant in 2022.