# On selection of dropdown retrieve data is null except the first item selection in google web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server

I am working on google web app. I want to retrieve data based on dropdown selection. I can retrieve data perfectly only on first item selection from dropdown and for the rest i am getting null array received. I have check the server side code by manually calling and its working fine and send data back perfectly. Problem is in client side code but I have no idea of this behavior. I would appreciate if some one help. Thank you in advance.

Here is the sheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yrQjp0_lU3iONW0FK3yCwm79CzD9KUW3Yg92Al5yoAo/edit?usp=sharing

Link to webapp
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyJdifqDE4NG3dhIsQDQT3f9xKYYfPBL4QXz3p6SZzz3_avdf3b/exec?v=updateevent

Here is the dropdown

[image]

Selection of first index item and got array in alert message

[image]

Selection of second item and got null array

[image]

When I pass the text manually to the below server side function for second and third item i get matching rows and retrieve response in array but using client side i got null array in response.

Here is my server side code:

```
function GetSelection(title) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet_ID");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Event_Info"); 
    var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;   
    var list  = sheet.getRange("A2:T" + Number(Alast)).getValues();
    Logger.log(list); 
    var values = []; 
    values.pop(); 

    for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i][0].toString().trim().toLowerCase() === title.toString().trim().toLowerCase()) {
          values.push([list[i][0], list[i][1], list[i][2], list[i][3], list[i][4]]); 
          return values;
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my client side code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
          <?!= include("CREATEEVENT-CS") ?>
      </head>
      <body onload="addList()">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-25">
                        <label> Event Type </label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-75">                   
                        <select id="selectNumber" onchange="jsFunction(this.value)">
                            <option>Choose a number</option>
                        </select>
                   </div>
             </div>

           <?!= include("UPDATEEVENT-JS") ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the data retrieval script:

```
        function jsFunction(value)
        {           
            alert(value);
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getpopuled).GetSelection(value); 
        }

  function getpopuled(dataarray) {
     alert(dataarray);
  }
```

Comment: *it doesn't works* is not a problem description. See [mcve]. Provide logs/alerts. Explicitly describe what happens and what was expected.

Comment: Thank you for identification. I have update the description.

Comment: Dates are not legal and are not allowed between client and server.

Comment: Is there a date in your sheet?

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values). You can solve it in two ways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50458186/

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I got the issue and consider answer of my problem. I had tried to retrieve all the data back in controls for edit, update and delete. Is there a way to use editable grid or table as we can do in asp.net. Your quick support is very much appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Better to ask a **new** question with [mcve].

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is not self-contained; it has volatile links to external code that no longer exhibits the problem that was reported, and therefore has little or no value for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved. I have change the server side code as date is a restricted data type to pass to client and will return null. 
So i convert dates to data types string.

```
function GetSelection(title){
    console.log(title); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet_ID");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName"); 
    var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;   
    var list  = sheet.getRange("A2:T" + Number(Alast)).getValues();
    Logger.log(list); 
    var values = []; 
    values.pop(); 
    for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
        if( list[i][0].toString().trim().toLowerCase() === title.toString().trim().toLowerCase() ){
            values.push([ list[i][0], list[i][1], list[i][2], list[i][3],  list[i][4].toString(), list[i][5].toString(),  list[i][6], list[i][7], list[i][8], list[i][9], list[i][10], list[i][11], list[i][12], list[i][13], list[i][14], list[i][15], list[i][16], list[i][17], list[i][18], list[i][19]]); 
       return values;
       }
    }
}
```

On client side i have used following to intialize date control from database and my problem solved. Thanks to

> TheMaster

for his contribution to explain the issue.

```
 document.getElementById("eedate").value = new Date(dataarray[0][5]).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```