# When I try to fetch data from Google Sheets, if this data contains a date or time, it is not fetched into the Google app script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I searched for this info in many websites, but unfortunately I did not find it. I used an app script from Google to fetch data from Google Sheet The code I used to get data from google sheet; Can't pass any data contains date or time, such as `2021/01/01` or `12:00 AM` or `12:00:00` but when removing date or time fetching data does work fine

Technologies used: google app script, google sheet

**The question is: How to fetch data, regardless of its type?**

**Code.gs** It works as it should

```
var ss1 = "1bqKXcD2uXUIegqsb4pwieuhwe29-3872_Kj50kfvvXU";
function getLicenseExpirationData(){

  //Get spread sheet with id = to var ss1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss1);
  //Get spread sheet named Reports
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Reports");
  //Get data from a spread sheet
  var LicenseExpirationData = ws.getRange(2, 1,ws.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues();
  //After geting all data return it so we can use it
  return LicenseExpirationData;
};
```

**TableScript.html** I guess the problem is here

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    //Get all result from google sheet and if you did get it display it or do display error
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateExpirationTable).getLicenseExpirationData();

    });
    //function name generateTable
    function generateExpirationTable(dataArray){
    //Display result inside in id with name ExpirationData
    var tbody = document.getElementById("ExpirationData");
    //Do this for each result
    dataArray.forEach(function(r){
        //Create Element <tr>
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        //Create Element <td> for column1
        var column1 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result1 inside <td>
        column1.textContent = r[0];
        //Create Element <td> for column2
        var column2 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result2 inside <td>
        column2.textContent = r[1];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column3 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result3 inside <td>
        column3.textContent = r[2];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column4 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result4 inside <td>
        column4.textContent = r[3];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column5 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result5 inside <td>
        column5.textContent = r[4];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column6 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result6 inside <td>
        column6.textContent = r[5];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column7 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result7 inside <td>
        column7.textContent = r[6];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column8 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result8 inside <td>
        column8.textContent = r[7];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column9 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result9 inside <td>
        column9.textContent = r[8];
        //Create Element <td> for column3
        var column10 = document.createElement("td");
        //Display result10 inside <td>
        column10.textContent = r[9];
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column1);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column2);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column3);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column4);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column5);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column6);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column7);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column8);
        //Move to next column
        row.appendChild(column9);
        //Move to next row
        row.appendChild(column10);
        //Move to next row
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    
    });
    };
    function showError() {
        alert('Error!');
    }
```

**View items as Html** It works as it should

```
<table class="mt-0 pt-0 table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Num</th>
        <th>Data2</th>
        <th>Data3</th>
        <th>Data4</th>
        <th>Data5</th>
        <th>Data6</th>
        <th>Data7</th>
        <tr>
      </thead>
      <!--Display table result on id body-table-->
      <tbody id="ExpirationData">
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: This is an explicitly stated behavior for client-server interaction in Apps Script in the reference documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null value returned to Apps Script webapp for a certain spreadsheet by server function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50457896/null-value-returned-to-apps-script-webapp-for-a-certain-spreadsheet-by-server-fu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. When retrieving date object from Google Sheets it is best to use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of `getValues()`
2. When passing arrays from code.gs to clientside - pass it as a string, that is: `JSON.stringify()` the array on Apps Script side before returning it a `JSON.parse()` it again on Javascript side

[parameters and return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)